# JavaScript && operator in visual editor

Tags: javascript, visual-editor

I am used to of adding javascript/jquery code in posts via visual editor but it seems I never used && operator cause wordpress is altering && operator in &. Here is a link where I am using &&.
http://demo.techstriders.com/corey/canyon/calculator/
I am wondering what is correct way of using javascript in wordpress visual editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**wp_enqueue_script**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for your javascript files instead of adding the code directly into the post content.

**ps:**
You can check out the callbacks on the `the_content` filter, using

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
        global $wp_filter;
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $wp_filter['the_content'],true));
});
```

to display them in the footer part of your theme. Then you will see callbacks like
`wpautop`,  `wptexturize`,  `convert_chars` and  `convert_smilies`.

I don't recommend it, but it is possible to remove these filters to use javascript code in the post content:

```
add_action('init','custom_init');
function custom_init() {
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
    remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
    remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_smilies');
}
```